# Removing IKEA "Vikarn" shower-curtain rod

Tags: shower

I need to remove my IKEA "Vikarn" shower-curtain rod. The screws are covered by a piece which is shown on page 10 of the [assembly instructions](https://www.ikea.com/se/sv/assembly_instructions/vikarn-duschdraperistang__AA-1752021-4_pub.pdf). This piece clicks on, as shown, but how can I get it off?  Neither twisting nor pulling seems to do the trick, and I've forgotten what the inside of the piece looks like.

Comment: Have you tried prying the piece apart with a small screw driver or butter knife?

Comment: Going with what ^^ said, try praying the bottom edge of the cover. My guess would be that the cover somehow connects with that screw that is inserted upwards. I also take it you are trying to repurpose this shower rod?

Answer (score 1):

The cap is very similar to a most any plastic lidded container with a tiny lip clicking over another tiny lip. UnhandledExcepSean would be correct that a little pry with a thin stiff device should pop them apart.

Sometimes in just 1 spot is all that's needed and other times you'll need 2 devices and walk the prying halfway around before they pop free. It just depends on precision and quality control differences between the caps, if any.